# Masking only a certain range of indices in numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, masking, masked-array

I have an ndarray. I need to mask any number less than 50 until the first number encountered is greater than 50. This should be done both at the beginning and at the end of a row. Right, when the first number encountered is >50, the masking should stop.

One row looks like:

```
    [ 0   1   1   0  57  121  120  157  77  14   0   3   0   0   0   0  67 100  
    98  97 101 129 139 105  97 105 181 126  10   0   0]
```

I want something like:

```
    [-- -- -- -- 57 121 120 157 77 14  0  3  0  0  0  0 67 100 98 97
 101 129 139 105 97 97 105 181 126 -- -- --]
```

The masking should stop right before 57 in the second line, and at 126 in the 4th last line.

I have tried ma.masked_where, but it masks the 0s in between as well, which I don't want.

So, if there a way to do this, or can you help me so that I can specify a range of indices, eg: `[0:40]` only which should be masked.

I do not want to change the dimension of the array after it is masked. Also, the presence of `--` wouldn't make a difference to my purpose.

Comment: What should the masking achieve? I am not seeing the expected output.

Comment: have made the changes.

Comment: What about the two `ones` at positions 29 and 30?

Comment: it should be masked, as all values which are less than 50 should be masked, until the first number encountered is greater than 50.

Comment: @a_ran Simply mention about the threshold (50) and don't confuse yourself and others with the zeros mention.

Comment: @Divakar I just saw what you meant. Have edited.

Comment: What is your region of interest? Are you using the mask to operate on/with the two ends or the middle - are you excluding the ends from your operations or excluding the middle?

Comment: @wwii This is just one row. I need to produce geojson files with the position of values belonging to a certain group, but I have to exclude the boundary values which are < 50.

Comment: Was the full size of your actual array really needed? Couldn't you make a more minimal example? Right now it's just annoying to look for what you are after...

Comment: Sure, I will do that.

Comment: @jpp's Boolean indexing solution (with a minor tweak) will *select* the middle which should be the same as excluding the ends.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use either Boolean indexing or manual iteration. The former is more efficient for small arrays; the latter for large arrays with a small number of out-of-scope values either side.

#### Boolean indexing

```
x = np.array([0, 0, 0, 2, 3, 51, 34, 1, 23, 32, 32, 52, 0, 0, 0])

start = (x > 50).argmax()
end = len(x) - (x[::-1] > 50).argmax()

print(x[start: end])

[51 34  1 23 32 32 52]
```

#### Manual iteration

Using `next` with a generator expression and `enumerate`:

```
start = next(idx for idx, val in enumerate(x) if val > 50)
end = len(x) - next(idx for idx, val in enumerate(reversed(x)) if val > 50)

print(x[start: end])

[51 34  1 23 32 32 12]
```

#### Masking

If you wish to replace out-of-scope values with `np.nan`, you can assign accordingly, remembering to convert to `float` first, as `NaN` values are `float`:

```
x = x.astype(float)
x[:start] = np.nan
x[end:] = np.nan

print(x)

array([nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, 51., 34.,  1., 23., 32., 32., 52., nan, nan, nan])
```

Comment: I do not want to change the dimension of the array. I have put the expected output.

Comment: @a_ran, `--` is not a valid element in a numeric array, I've edited to include a solution to replace with `np.nan`.

Comment: I agree, but that wouldn't matter in what I want to achieve.

Comment: @jpp I'm gleaning this from hints in the question, but OP appears to be looking to manipulate the mask in a masked array. `--` appears to be a valid printout in that case.